# Find the frequency and location of a recurring word in a cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find, frequency

How can I find() the location of the Nth occurrence of a word in a sentence in a cell?

Example:

```
Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall. Humpty had a great fall.
```

In above i want to find the total occurrences and the location of the word 'Humpty'.

Expected Result:

```
Occurances  location
1            1  
2            30
```

Is there any way in which I can know the above?

I want to use the location of the 2nd occurrence and calculate further if there are more than 2 occurrences of the target word.

Thanks!

Comment: There can be more than 2 as well, but majority of my work gets done in the first 2 occurances. However there might be cases where i have to go beyond 2 as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) you can use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(FIND($B$2,$B$1,1+IFERROR(VALUE(B4),0)),"not found")
```

Which basically says:

Find the target (`Humpty`) in the sample text (`Humpty dumpty etc..`) and start searching from the next position to the last found. If no more target text is found, return `not found`. The `IFERROR(VALUE(B4),0))` prevents an error for the first search which should always start from position 1, but needs to ignore the fact it is checking the `location` label.

Here's a screenshot of the implementation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
=IFERROR(FIND("@@@",SUBSTITUTE($A$1,$B$4,"@@@",$A6)),"")
```

See image for reference:

[image]